# Get names of columns when allows null values

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

I want to get the column names in a certain table when this column allows null values.

I don't found this in [Pragma statements support](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html) from [sqlite.org](https://www.sqlite.org/). Can you help me?

I think could be a pragma statement like this:

```
PRAGMA allow_nulls(TABLE_NAME);
```

Answer (score 0):

according to [this](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/using-sqlite/9781449394592/re205.html) page you can get `notnull` information from `table_info`.

```
public List<String> getNullableColumns(SQLiteDatabase db, String tableName) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

    Cursor columns = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA table_info('" + tableName + "')", null);
    if (columns.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            if (columns.getInt(3) == 0)) {
                result.add(columns.getString(1));
            }
        }
        while (columns.moveToNext());
    }
    columns.close();
    return result;
}
```